# How to tell if DavFS is installed?

Tags: davfs2

Obviously a noob question, but I'm playing with mounting a webdav folder in Linux, and trying to tell if the davfs is already installed. Googling shows this command to supposedly list all installed filesystems:

`cat /proc/filesystems`

Problem is, running that command before installing davfs (not shown in the screenshot) and after installing (shown), shows the exact same list of installed fs', which does *not* show davfs:

[image]

Is there a better way to show if davfs is in fact, installed?

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `apt` for the install, you may simply search it:

```
apt search davfs

davfs2/stable 1.5.5-1 amd64
  mount a WebDAV resource as a regular file system
```

As you can see, in my case the package is found in the repositories, but not installed. In contrast to e.g. `vim`:

```
 apt search vim 

vim/stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 amd64 [installed]
  Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
```

---

Alternatively (and a bit more save - it will also apply to packages not from the repositories but also manually installed via `.deb`-files) use `dpgk` to list all local and grep the package name

```
dpkg -l | grep davfs
```

(empty in my case)

```
dpkg -l | grep vim

ii  vim    2:8.1.0875-5   amd64  Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
```

Where `ii` indicates "installed".

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/filesystems` shows only filesystems supported by kernel. DavFS support is implemented using [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) in userspace so it's not shown there. The best best way to check is probably simply to check whether `mount.davfs` binary exists (for example using `which`).

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/filesystems` only lists the file systems that are currently known to the kernel. But upon a `mount(src, dst, fstype, ...)`, the kernel will try to dynamically load the corresponding kernel module if available and not already  loaded.

Some filesystems such as `nfs` or `aufs` need a helper program to setup the mount. That will be `mount.fsname`. On Debian bullseye, the first thing the `mount` command does when asked to mount a FS with `-t fsname` is look for a `mount.fsname` in `/sbin`, `/sbin/fs.d` and `/sbin/fs` in that order.

`davfs2` is a file system implemented in user space. The kernel driver will be `fuse`, and a `mount.davfs2` helper will be responsible for starting the userspace program and connect it with `fuse`.

So here, to check whether a `fsname` is available, you could do:

```
has_fs() {
  [ -e "/sbin/mount.$1" ]        || # helper found in /sbin
    [ -e "/sbin/fs.d/mount.$1" ] || # helper found in /sbin/fs.d
    [ -e "/sbin/fs/mount.$1" ]   || # helper found in /sbin/fs
    < /proc/filesystems FS=$1 awk '
      $NF == ENVIRON["FS"] {found = 1; exit}
      END {if (!found) exit 1}'  || # currently available in kernel
    modprobe -c | FS=fs_$1 awk '
      $1 == "alias" && $2 == ENVIRON["FS"] {found = 1; exit}
      END {if (!found) exit 1}'     # available via a kernel module
}
```

The search path for the  mount helper may be different on different systems. Note that the availability of the helper is a strong indication, but not a guarantee that the driver will be available (or that you'll be able to mount a FS of that type).